# Firefox does not pick up CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox

This problem is related to the website www.oikotrust.gr.

I have two viewports set up, up to and over 900 pixels width, so that a different CSS is loaded each time.

It works well in Chrome... It works well in Firefox below 900 pixels. But it ***does not*** work in Firefox over 900 pixels (that is, the CSS is not loaded).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 901px)" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 900px)" href="css/mobile-device.css">
```

Comment: The website looks the same to me in FF and Chrome, showing the larger icon on the wider screen in both browsers. Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: yes i have. Are the links on the left hand side menu underlined in both of your browsers? (if yes then it means the css is not picked up)

Comment: Hm, no, so it doesn't look the same in both browsers. The links are blue and underlined in FF, but black and not underlined in Chrome. The rest of the layout has much of the same differences though (larger font size, hamburger menu on narrower screens etc)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your CSS code that you need to fix. The site https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ is good for validating code. Just type your website address in the address bar.

When you type your address in, it gives you four errors. You will notice that the first error references line 33, but it is actually complaining about the double quote that it found on line 32. That double quote might be throwing off all the rest of your code.